# Elementary Operations on Sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a set with subsets $A$ and $B$. Prove:

a). $X \setminus (X \setminus A) =A$.

$X \setminus A$ is the set of all points of $X$ which do not belong to $A$. Given $p \in X$, we will show that if $p \in A$, then $p \in X \setminus (X \setminus A)$. Suppose $p \in X \setminus (X \setminus A)$ which means that $p\in \{ x: x\in X$ and $x \notin (X \setminus A)\}$. Let $B = X \setminus A$. If $p \notin B$, then $p \notin X \setminus A$, so $p \notin X$ and $p \in A$. Therefore, $ X \setminus (X \setminus A)=A$.

b). If $A \subset B$, then $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$.

Suppose $p \in X \setminus B$ which means that $p \in \{x: x \in X$ and $x \notin B \}$. If, $p \notin B$, then $p \notin A$ since $A \subset B$. Suppose $p \in X \setminus A$ which means that $p \in \{x: x \in X $ and $x \notin A\}$. Given $p \in X$, we will show that if $p \in X \setminus B$, then $p \in X \setminus A$ too: $p \in X \setminus B$ means $p \in X$ and $p \notin B$. If $p \notin B$, then $p \notin A$ since $A \subset B$. By definition, $p\in X \setminus A$, so $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$.

c). $A \subset B$ if and only if $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$.

$A\subset B \Rightarrow X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$ is part (b) above.

Suppose $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$. We want to show that $p \in X$ and $p \notin B$ implies $A \subset B$. If $p \in X$ and $p \notin B$, then we can write $B = B \cup (B \setminus A)$. So $p \in X$ and $p \notin B \cup (B \setminus A)$. Since $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, then $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$ which is the hypothesis in this direction. But $p \notin X \setminus B$ implies that $ p \notin X \setminus A$. But $p \notin X \setminus B$ means $ p \in (X \setminus B)^c$ and similarly for $X \setminus A$. So if $p \in (X \setminus B)^c$, then $p \in (X \setminus A)^c$ which shows that $ A \subset B$.

d). $X \setminus A \subset B$ if and only if $A \cup B =X$.

If $X = A \cup B$, then $p\in X \Rightarrow p \in A \cup B$. We want to show that this implies $p \in X$ and $p \notin A$ is in $B$. Since $p \in X \Rightarrow p \in A \cup B$, then we have $p \in A \cup B$ and $p \notin A$ which shows that $p \in B$, or equivalently, $(X \setminus A) \subset B = (A \cup B) \setminus A \subset B$.

Now suppose $X \setminus A \subset B$ which means that for some $p \in X \setminus A$, then we get that $p \in B$ as well. Our goal is to show that this implies that $X = A \cup B$. If $p \in X$ and $p \notin A$ is a subset of $B$, then what is in $X$ but not in $A$ is all contained in $B$. The only way to ensure this is to have $X = A \cup B$.

e). $A \subset X \setminus B$ if and only if $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. We want to prove that this implies $A \subset X \setminus B$. Given that $X$ is a set and $A$ and $B$ are subsets, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$ is in $X$.

If $A \subset X \setminus B$, then for some $p\in A$, $p$ is also in the set $\{ p \in X$ and $p \notin B\}$. So if $p \in A$, and $p \notin B$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$ as required.

f). $A \setminus B = A \cap (X \setminus B)$

If $p \in A$ and $p \notin B$, then we want to show that $p \in A$ and $p \notin B$ is the same as $p \in A$ **and** $p \in X$ and $p \notin B$. If $p \in A$ and $ p \in X$ but not in $B$, then we want to leave out the remainder of $X$. However, this is satisfied precisely by intersecting $A$ with $X \setminus B$, that is, $ A \setminus B = A \cap (X \setminus B)$ by the inclusion of the intersection.

g). $X \setminus (A \setminus B) = B \cup (X \setminus A)$

$B \cup (X \setminus A)$ is like saying $p \in B$ or $ p \in X$ and $p \notin A$. If I negate the second part of this statement, won't I have $p \in X$ and $\neg (p \in A$ and $p \notin B) \Rightarrow p \in X$ and $ p \notin A $ or $p \in B$?
Therefore, $p \in X$ and $p \notin A$ and $p \in X$ or $p \in B$, but $B$ is a subset of $X$. So $X \setminus (A \setminus B) = B \cup (X \setminus A)$.

First of all, I want to thank you for taking the time to read this rather lengthy question since there is seven parts to it. As always, any assistance is greatly appreciated. When I draw a picture illustrating the problem, I can see the conclusion, but I need clarification when it comes to making a more rigorous proof.

The reason I added the Topology tag is because I am using the textbook *Principles of Topology* by Fred. H Croom.

Comment: I couldn't follow all the arguments you gave. Some contains mathematical mistakes. Mostly your ideas are correct. But you need to write them more clearly (especially if you want someone to follow them). I gave a proof (see the answer) for those facts (not very different from your arguments). Feel free to ask if you have any question.

Comment: Look at the answer by *Troy Woo* in the following link (same question but different approach). If you can't understand all of it right now, that's also fine. But it's worth knowing. You can always come back later to take a look at it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122128/principles-of-topology-operations-on-sets-union-intersection-and-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a). $X \setminus (X \setminus A) =A.$

Note that $x \notin X \setminus A \Leftrightarrow x \in A.$ Thus $x \in X \setminus (X \setminus A) \Leftrightarrow x \notin X \setminus A \Leftrightarrow x \in A.$

(b). $A\subset B \Rightarrow X\setminus B \subset X\setminus A.$

Let $x \in X\setminus B.$ Then $x \in X, x \notin B.$ Since $A \subset B, x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin A.$ So $x \in X \setminus A.$

(c). $A\subset B \Leftrightarrow  X\setminus B \subset X\setminus A.$

By (b) we have $A\subset B \Rightarrow X\setminus B \subset X\setminus A.$ To show the reverse inclusion, note that it's enough to show that $x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin A.$ If $x \notin B,$ then $x \in X \setminus B \Rightarrow x \in X \setminus A \Rightarrow x \notin A.$

(d). $X\setminus A \subset B \Leftrightarrow  A\cup B=X.$

($\Rightarrow$) Note that $A \cup B \subseteq X.$ Now suppose $x \in X.$ If $x \in A,$ then $x \in A \cup B.$ If $x \notin A,$ then $x \in X \setminus A \subset B$ and so $x \in A \cup B.$ ($\Leftarrow$) Let $x \in X \setminus A.$ Then $x \in X$ and $x \notin A.$ But $X=A\cup B.$ So we must have $x \in B.$

(e). $A \subset X\setminus B \Leftrightarrow  A\cap B=\emptyset.$

($\Rightarrow$) If $x \in A \cap B,$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and this contradicts the fact that $A \subset X \setminus B.$ ($\Leftarrow$) Let $x \in A.$ Since $A \cap B = \emptyset, x \notin B.$ So $x \in X \setminus B.$

(f). $A \setminus B = A \cap (X \setminus B).$

$x \in A \setminus B \Leftrightarrow x \in A$ and $x \notin B \Leftrightarrow x \in A$ and $x \in X \setminus B \Leftrightarrow x \in A \cap (X \setminus B).$

(g). $X \setminus (A \setminus B) = B \cup (X \setminus A).$

($\Rightarrow$)Let $x \in X \setminus (A \setminus B).$ Suppose $x \notin B.$ Then $x \in X, x \notin A\setminus B \Rightarrow x \in X, x \notin A \Rightarrow x \in X \setminus A.$ If $x \notin X \setminus A,$ then $x \in A.$ So from the condition $x \in X, x \notin A\setminus B,$ we must have $x \in B.$ ($\Leftarrow$)Let $x \in B \cup (X \setminus A).$ If $x \in X \setminus A,$ then $x \notin A$ and so $ x\notin A \setminus B.$ Hence $x \in X \setminus (A \setminus B).$ Now suppose $x \in B.$ If $x \notin A,$ by the same argument we are done. If $x \in A,$ then $x \notin A \setminus B.$ So $x \in X \setminus (A \setminus B).$